# OpenOffice inserted xml not visible for reading (but visible in xml source)

Tags: xml, libreoffice

I have problem with generating and inserting xml in existing document.

```
 <table:table table:template-name="default">
                <table:table-column />
                <table:table-column />
                <table:table-column />
                <table:table-row>
                  <table:table-cell>
                    <text:p>1</text:p>
                  </table:table-cell>
                  <table:table-cell>
                    <text:p>2</text:p>
                  </table:table-cell>
                  <table:table-cell>
                    <text:p>3</text:p>
                  </table:table-cell>
                </table:table-row>
</table:table>
```

This code i successfully inserted in document (and it visible in document xml) but not visible for reading. Bottom line: Inserted xml exists in source, but not visible.

xml table example taken from: http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=28229

Note: Generated document xml is valid - no tag mismatch here.

And im using OpenOffice template document (.ott)

Comment: Something more for investigation: im inserting `table` tag after closing `</text:span></text:p>`. So table is not inserted in the some `p` or `span` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my bad :)
I also was using `<table:list>` and should first close these tags:

```
</text:list-item></text:list>
```